# pyodbc encoding question: big5 text is being mangled

Tags: python, windows, unicode, odbc

I am reading from a pyodbc connection with source data which is probably encoded in big5.

for example:

```
cursor = myob_cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(f"select * from {tablename}")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

in the rows list,
an address column can look like this:

```
s=rows[8628][3]

'¤EÀs»ò¦a¹D62¸¹¥Ã¦w¼s³õ2¼Ó8«Ç'
```

This is probably big5; the source is a Hong Kong MYOB file. If I use the export feature of this application and open in big5 encoding, I get chinese characters.
MYOB stores data in a file, and I think it follows the encoding of the Windows machine (which is big5). I am running my code on such a Windows desktop, so my 32 bit python 3.7 environment is the same as the MYOB executable.

If I save that 'string' via vi and open it in big5 encoding, I get chinese characters, but also some errors, errors which are not present in the application's export feature.

python thinks it is a string.
I have tried passing big5 encoding to pyodbc but it makes no difference.
that is, `myob_cnxn.setencoding(encoding="big5") #this is not going to work, and it doesn't`

I am stuck with no good ideas. I think if I could get binary results not decoded strings, I may have a chance, but I don't actually know what I am getting with pyodbc and this connection

---

The answer came from @lenz (so far, in a comment).

This is my implementation, which uses errors = "ignore" and therefore throws away some characters. For me, this an acceptable outcome for this data.

```
   big5_decoded = value.encode("latin",errors="ignore").decode("big5",errors="ignore")
```

Comment: If I round-trip encode your example with `.encode('latin1').decode('big5')` I do get Chinese characters mixed with ASCII digits (I have no way of telling if the result makes sense). I'm not proposing this as a work-around – you should get the connection to handle encoding properly – but it may help you nonetheless.

Comment: However, it's also possible that the DB had been set up with mismatching encoding when the data were entered, such that the DB holds the distorted data, nominally.

Comment: Your round trip idea is the solution, or at least a workaround that gives the correct outcome, which is good enough for me in this case. You could create an answer so I can vote for it and accept it.
 I pasted the outcome into google translate and it is perfect.

 Initially I tried roundtripping from utf8 to big5, but the result was an error (illegal multibyte sequence') .utf7 looks like a dead end. I gave up, because I don't understand much about encoding. Why does latin work?

Comment: ... ah, latin is a strictly one byte encoding.

Comment: Exactly, Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) is a 1-to-1 mapping of byte values to Unicode codepoints, which is handy for encoding-related plumbing. I'm hesitant to post this as an answer, because it's (presumably) fixing the symptoms, not the root of the problem. (It's quite likely that you can't fix the cause of the problem, because someone else messed up the encoding earlier...)

Comment: Do you know where in the stack I end up with a python string? When I read documentation, older versions of odbc really only worked with with fixed width data (which in this case is exactly correct). Somehow I end with a string, but it seems that really I have a binary value.

Comment: Sorry, no idea...

Comment: My working hypothesis is: The data in the database is strictly single-byte; the application is not unicode aware. Windows has a system-wide locale for non-unicode apps, set to big5. At various points in the stack, but always at 'application layer', Windows intercepts the single bytes and applies this decoding (it's a hack, changing the setting in Control Panel does not touch the database). The odbc connection is under this level and it can only return single byte data. Your workaround does the same thing Windows does, in effect (but we get real unicode), I doubt there is any other solution.